# How can i put two variables into blade view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

It is just for learning purposes.

But how do one put two different tables into one view in Laravel.

So far i tried with use DB;
As its just to learn and havent done the model for that table.

Here is my code.

```
public function view($id, $slug = null){
    
    $first = DB::table('first')->get();
    $second = Second::where('id',$id)->where('status','active')->firstOrFail();
    
    $uriCampaign = $this->request->path();
    
    if( str_slug( $second->title ) == '' ) {
            $slugUrl  = '';
        } else {
            $slugUrl  = '/'.str_slug( $second->title );
        }
        
        $url_second = 'second/'.$second->id.$slugUrl;

        
        
        $uriCanonical = $url_second;
        
        if( $uriCampaign != $uriCanonical ) {
            return redirect($uriCanonical);
        }
        
    return view('test.view')->withResponse($second,$first);
    
}
```

So i can get the $second into blade, but not the $first.
How can i get them both that i can show, {{ $second->name }}. and also {{ $first->name }}

It doesnt have to be anything frome this code, but just in general.
If i dont want to use model, is it possible with just use DB or there has to be a model to support it?

Comment: `return view('test.view')->withResponse(['second' => $second, 'first' => $first]);`

Comment: The manual has a page [Passing Data To Views](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#passing-data-to-views). Laravel/Blade doesn't care where the data comes from. You can use `{{ dd($first) }}` and `{{ dd($second) }}` inside blade to see if they contain anything

Comment: For learning purposes, I suggest starting with the docs.